# Getting membersRemoved in context.activity for conversationUpdate in Bot Framework v4 for personal scope from msteams

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Receiving `membersRemoved` in `context.activity` for `conversationUpdate` in Bot Framework v4 (Javascript) for **personal** scope from ***msteams***. According to the documentation `membersRemoved` is received when a member is removed from a **Team** or **channel** in which bot is added, but in our case bot is only enabled for **personal** scope. Can anyone help with the scenario when we can receive `memberRemoved` for `personal` channel, so that it can be handled properly in code.

[image: Image for context.activity JSON]

[image: Image for Bot Config]

Comment: Did you mean group chat instead of personal scope?

Comment: @user2297037 No, I meant about personal scope only , in the also JSON also you see that `conversationType` property value is `personal`.

Comment: As Kyle Delaney explained there is no scenario when you should receive that event for personal scope, an User cannot leave a 1:1 chat.
Can you explain better your scenario from a User perspective, please?

Comment: Keeping in mind that for **personal** scope we will never get `memberRemoved` for `conversationUpdate`, we written code only for checking `membersAdded`.  But during the process of analyzing our logs for user conversations, we found that we are receiving `membersRemoved` also for personal scope. But we don't know that for which user it is coming as due to privacy policy we don't log data using which user can be identified. So, we don't know about the scenario for which we are receiving `membersRemoved` and as we don't know the scenario we are not able to decide what action to be taken for it.

Comment: **Continuing previous comment due to length restriction** ---   But, we are receiving this type of message from **Microsoft Teams** almost 3-4 times a week and one more thing I like to add that we also searched if there is some other `messageType` also coming for same `conversationId` for which we are getting `memberRemoved` but never found other logs for it. It always a standalone `membersRemoved` with unique `conversationID`.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta, Can you check the "channelData" property values for the memberRemoved payload

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT It is already present in the JSON shared previously i.e. `"channelData": {"tenant": {"id": "tenant_id"}}` 

Comment: @SaurabhGupta I missed that part. I am discussing this with Bot Framework Team.

Answer (score 2):

Personal conversations in Teams are permanent. There is no scenario when you should receive `membersRemoved` in a personal conversation.

Comment: Ya exactly that's why I am confused how we are getting this from Teams for personal scope, I tried to connect with Microsoft folks using portal.azure support but they asked me to raise this issue by buying a premier support ticket.

Comment: Okay, your question was unfortunately unclear. I wish you had said "we are getting this activity and we don't want to" to distinguish your problem from "we are not getting this activity and we do want to."

Comment: This is my first post on stack overflow, sorry if it was not clear . Actually my question is just to get the scenario when it can come so that we can write proper code to handle it. But as per documentation and also your valuable reply, we should not have received it in the first place for `personal` scope.

Comment: If you share your app manifest then I can inspect it for clues, but this is most likely something that will require privileged access to Teams internals to investigate rather than something that can be solved by the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Here's the link to [manifest.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GtK8Bd4I7L_eNNZDm6hXGSqVRouJlmOq/view?usp=sharing) file structure we are using.

Comment: Okay I don't see any clues there. I tried installing and uninstalling a Teams manifest and I can get members added for personal conversations but I can only get members removed from team conversations. I can't reproduce your issue and there's no way for me to figure out what's going on based on the information available. You will need to raise a ticket to have this investigated internally. Perhaps your bot ID was included in another app manifest that you're not aware of, and people are installing your bot in teams or group chats.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the **JSON** we are getting `"conversationType": "personal"` when we are getting `membersRemoved`. So, I think it can't be that case. But many many thanks for investing time for the same .

Comment: All right, well I've heard from Teams that this seems to be related to a bug and they're working on it. if you're not willing to get support from Teams directly, would you be willing to accept this answer as the best you could get outside of Teams?

Comment: How can I get support from Teams directly, could you help me with this?

Comment: You can click the feedback button in Teams or have a look at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

We found in the log that user is being soft deleted by data retention from the 1:1 thread with bot before the thread gets deleted. We're following up internal folks to understand if this has always been the case. Will report back once we know more.